# Password Access with Multiple Instances

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I am designing an application that will require users to first login and then access several secure web pages.  I plan on using AWS along with the AWS Load Balancer and expect several AWS instances of this application to be running.  What is the "best practice" for persisting security credentials across several web pages and several instances?  The user will login and then navigate through several secure web pages.  I presume the AWS Load Balancer will be round-robin redirecting each https request to a different server instance.  How does each instance know that the user has successfully logged in?  Also, how do I keep the secure pages secure from external access?  The platform will be Linux, Java, and Spring-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I presume the AWS Load Balancer will be round-robin redirecting each
>   https request to a different server instance.

That's the default ELB behavior, but you can enable [sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html) on the Elastic Load Balancer to lock a user to a specific back-end server, at which point the HTTP session stored on that one server keeps track of the user's authentication state.

> How does each instance know that the user has successfully logged in?

They don't, unless you configure a shared session store of some kind. I prefer using Redis (ElastiCache) as a shared session store. Of course if you enable sticky sessions at the ELB that might prevent the need for a shared session store.

> Also, how do I keep the secure pages secure from external access?  The
>   platform will be Linux, Java, and Spring-boot.

That's not really a feature of AWS. You would need to add security to your application. Look into [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/).

Comment: Hello Mark, I presume that I can use the users IP address as the key and an application unique security authorization as the value?  I can use the Redis expire feature to eventually remove the key value pair if the user does not log out.  Would that be your approach?

Comment: No, that's not the approach I would take at all. You are trying to roll your own security system when this problem has already been solved for you. Also using IP address is a terrible idea as there is no guarantee that each user will have a unique IP. You need to look into using Spring Security, and use a Tomcat session manager that uses Redis as it's storage backend. You shouldn't try to manage user sessions yourself.

Comment: Hello Mark, Great input.  Can you give me a couple of the names of the security components that I should be looking at?  Spring documentation is voluminous.  However, it tends to focus more on procedure than a big picture drill down.  I want to understand the components of interest and get a big picture.